# Reconstruction a signal from random samples with holes

Tags: algorithm

I've encountered the following problem as part of my master thesis, and having been unable to find a suitable solution over the last few weeks I will ask the masses.

**The problem 1**

Assume there exist an (unknown) sequence of symbols of a known length. Say for instance

```
ABCBACBBBAACBAABCCBABBCA...  # 2000 Symbols long
```

Now, given *N* samples from arbitrary positions in the sequence, the task is to reconstruct the original sequence. For instance:

```
ABCBACBBBAA
ACBBBAACBAABCCBAB
CBACBBBAACBAAB
BAABCCBABBCA
...
```

**The problem 2 (Harder)**

Now, on the bright side, there is no limit to how many samples I can make, whilst on the not so bright side there is more to the story.

1. The samples are noisy. i.e. There might be errors.
2. There are known holes in the samples. I am only able to observe every 4-6th symbol.

Thus the samples are actually looking more like this:

```
A   A     A
A    A   A   C
C   B     B
B     B    C*     # The C should have been an A.
...
```

**I have tried the following:**

Let *S* be the set of all partial noisy sequences with holes.

- Greedy algorithm with random sampling and sliding window.

  1. Let *X* be the the "best" sequence thus far.
  2. Set *X* as a random sample from *S*.
  3. Choose a sequence *v* from *S*
  4. Slide *v* along *X* and score the match, and choose the "best" sequence as the new *X*.
  5. Repeat from 3.

  The problem with this algorithm is that I have been unable to find a good metric to score the sequences. Especially when considering the holes + noise. The result tended to favor shorter sequences, and the result was highly divergent in subsequent runs. Ideas to resolve this are most welcome.
- Trying to align the start of the sequence.

  This approach attempted to use the fact that I *might* be able to identify a suffix in the strings that likely make up beginning of the unknown sequence. However, due to the holes in the samples, I would need to shift even the matching sequences a few steps right or left. This results in exponential complexity and makes the problem intractable.
- I have also played with the idea of using a Hidden Markov Model, but am thwarted on how to deal with the missing data.
- Other ideas include, trying max flow through a graph built from the strings (don't think this will work), trellis decoding [Viterbi] (don't see how I can deal with samples starting in the middle of the unknown sequence) and more.

Any fresh Ideas are very welcome. Links/references to relevant articles are like manna!

**Specific information about my data set**

- I have three symbols S (start), A and B.
- I am `< 60%` certain any given symbol is sampled correctly.
- The S symbol should only appear a few times at the start of the master sequence, but does occur more often due to misclassification.
- The symbol B occurs about 1.5 times as often as A in the master sequence.

Comment: How do you know in that first case that the individual subsequences overlap at all? ie. what if you just lay them end to end?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I don't *know* that per ce, but I have a sufficient number of samples that it is safe to assume that many will.

Comment: I'm having a hard time formalizing the idea, but it seems conceptually similar to the problem solved by Dynamic Time Warping, at least with regard to the problem of aligning the signals correctly. Maybe there's some inspiration there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1 is known as the Shortest Common Supersequence problem. It is NP-hard for more than two input strings, even with only two symbols. Problem 2 is an instance of [Multiple Sequence Alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_sequence_alignment). There are many algorithms and implementations for it, mostly heuristic since it is also NP-hard in general.